# Stiff Stochastic differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a stochastic differential equation that has stiffness under some range of parameters. Therefore using numerical simulations for this system can end up with a divergent behavior. Using methods such as BDF and Radau from `scipy.optimize.solve_ivp` also didn't help with my problem. My guess is that this is because of the stochastic term in my equations. What would you do in such situations? Are there some packages that deal with stiffness and stochasticity at the same time? Or is there a method that can be implemented?
Here's the SDE:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{z_1} = \lambda(t) - z_1 + \sqrt{\lambda}dW ;
\dot{z_2} = z_1 - z_2 ;
\cdots
\dot{z_{n}} = z_{n-1} - z_n
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
\lambda(t) = \exp(\beta_1 z_1 + \beta_2 z_2 + \cdots)
$$
As you see the $\lambda(t)$ term will make this problem stiff.

Comment: Does it help any to reduce the dimension by writing everything in terms of just $z_1$? (Since $z_k = e^{-t} z_k(0) + e^{-t} \int_0^t e^s z_{k-1}(s) ds$ for $k=2,3,\dots$)

Comment: The stability question I would have is whether $\beta_i$ are such that there exists a solution to $\exp(x^* \sum \beta_i)=x^*$. Because somehow this process wants to fluctuate around $(x^*,x^*,\dots,x^*)$ unless no such $x^*$ even exists.

Comment: Good point @Ian. The stability constraints are met. The fixed point of this system is $z^\ast = \frac{-W(-\sum \beta_i)}{\sum \beta_i)}$ and for
$[-1/e, \infty)$ the fixed point exists. The divergence coming from the stiffness of the system as the jacobian shows the system is stable.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, it would be great if I can reduce the dimension (for later investigations such as bifurcation analysis) I give it a shot with this inspiration you provide.

and I just need to mention that $W$ function that I mentioned earlier is the Lambert-W function.

Comment: Trying to write everything in terms of $z_1$ didn't work as $k=2$ component is dependent on $k=1$. @Ian thanks for suggestion.

Comment: You can still do it anyway, at the bottom you have $z_2=e^{-t} z_2(0) + e^{-t} \int_0^t e^s z_1(s) ds$ and then you can plug that into the equation for $z_1$. It doesn't solve the whole problem completely of course, but you get an equation only involving $z_1$...though all the integrals inside might be a problem, I dunno.